# Filtering Databases with dplyr and Unix Timestamps

Tags: r, dplyr, unix-timestamp

I'm working with a large database (via `dplyrimpaladb`) and `dplyr`. Due to this I need to filter by date all of which are given in Unix timestamps. While I can convert it locally as

```
time_t = as.Date(as.POSIXct(time_t/1000, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC')))`
```

This does not work when communicating with DB; I need to translate the following into `dplyr`.

```
dau <- bb %>%
  tbl(sql("SELECT
             device_token_s,
             to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) AS dte
           FROM bb.sys_app_open
           WHERE 
             build_type_n = 1
             AND to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) >=  '2016-02-26'
           GROUP BY 
             device_token_s,
             to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint)))")) %>%
  collect()
```

The closest I could get was,

```
dau.df <- bb %>% 
  tbl('sys_app_open') %>%
  select(device_token_s, 
         sql('to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) AS dte')) %>%
  filter(build_type_n == 1, 
         sql("to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) >=  '2016-02-26' ")) %>%
  #mutate(collector_date_t = sql('to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint)))')) %>%
  group_by(device_token_s, sql('to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint)))')) %>%
  collect()
```

But I receive a

> ```
> Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
> The following do not:
> *  sql("to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) as dte")
> ```

Comment: [Unix time _is_ POSIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Can you show what your data looks like? What are you trying to do with it? Can you work with it in its current format?

Answer (score 0):

Post a sample data frame. I had the same problem; if I see the data frame once I can tell you how to do this using dplyr.

And if you are unable to do this quickly, I would suggest using `dbGetQuery(connection, "YOUR_SQL_QUERY")` to get the data.

Comment: If you are asking for some additional information, please use the comment instead of posting an answer. You can always add the answer later.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the way you are using the `select` function. You are trying to send a 'literal' SQL instruction via a `select` and you should be doing this via the `mutate` function.

This should work for you:

```
dau.df <- bb %>% 
  tbl('sys_app_open') %>%
  select(device_token_s, build_type_n, collector_date_t) %>%
  mutate(dte = sql("to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint)))")) %>%
  filter(build_type_n == 1, dte > '2016-02-26') %>%
  group_by(device_token_s, dte) %>%
  collect
```

I recommend you use the function `dbplyr::sql_render()` to view the query that `dplyr` is creating. For example, run

```
bb %>% 
  tbl('sys_app_open') %>%
  select(device_token_s, build_type_n, collector_date_t) %>%
  mutate(dte = sql("to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint)))")) %>%
  filter(build_type_n == 1, dte > '2016-02-26') %>%
  dbplyr::sql_render()
```

to look at the following query created:

```
<SQL> SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "device_token_s", "build_type_n", "collector_date_t", to_date(from_unixtime(cast(collector_date_t/1000 as bigint))) AS "dte"
FROM (SELECT "device_token_s", "build_type_n", "collector_date_t"
FROM "sys_app_open") "fgyyfaqrwp") "nmmczsfuid"
WHERE (("build_type_n" = 1) AND ("dte" > '2016-02-26'))
```